# Recursively delete directory except for some files in Windows

Tags: windows, shell

In Windows, I need to recursively delete a directory except for a short list of files to be kept.  The files may be nested in subdirectories.

I tried making the files read-only before running "rmdir /s", but it doesn't work.  Read-only files cannot be deleted directly, but they are deleted when inside a subdirectory being deleted with "rmdir /s".

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with some batch code, but it's fairly long:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Delete files not containing "foo"
for /r MyDir %%i in (*) do (
  set temp=%%~nxi
  if "!temp:foo=!"=="!temp!" (
    del "%%i"
  )
)

:: Build recursive list of dirs, sorted by deepest first
set dirs=
for /r MyDir /d %%i in (*) do (
  set dirs="%%i" !dirs!
)

:: Delete dirs.  Nonempty dirs will be skipped.
for %%i in (%dirs%) do (
  rmdir %%i
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you really can't have it both ways -- either the delete is recursive (everything goes) or it is not recursive (you explicitly list what you want gone).

The only reason the kind of read-only trick you tried works on Unix systems is because the failure/error propagates up the tree (you can't delete something that still has children), and it would appear from your test that Windows is less particular about that.

Comment: Windows won't let you remove a non-empty directory, but the `/s` option for rmdir overrides the read-only flag.  It would work if you changed the permissions on the files to read-only rather than setting the flag.

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for desired files.
2. When found, copy desired files/folder tree to temporary location.

   - Robocopy with the correct options can preserve attributes and time stamps.
3. Delete directory.
4. Copy files/folder tree back to original location.
5. ...?
6. Profit!

A better scripter than I could probably automate the whole thing in a couple lines, using robocopy, even.  Off the top of my head, I'm thinking maybe you copy out the list of files you want and use the `/MIR` option to blow away everything in the original directory that's not in the target directory.

Answer (score -1):

Hidden files are not deleted.

1. attrib +h for the files not to delete
2. delete all the files
3. del the empty directories
4. attrib +h the files saved.

Vg :

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir "My Dir\\*.log" /b /s') do attrib +h "%i"
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir "My Dir" /b /s') do del "%i" /q
rmdir /s
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir "My Dir" /b /s /ah') do attrib -h "%i"
```

Comment: `Hidden files are not deleted.`  Under what circumstances?  They most certainly are when I go to delete a directory, as well as they way the OP tried doing it at first.

Comment: Within a cmd window, you can't delete hidden files, just because the dir command can't see them as they are hidden

Comment: Not really the case, no.  Try `dir /a` or `attrib`.

Comment: And that's why you have

Comment: Sorry. That'why you have 'dir "My Dir" /b /s' and not 'dir "My Dir" /b /s /a' in the for command

Comment: And you must force the deletion of hidden files with del /ah. The default del don't

Comment: Right, the point is that maybe you should include this information in your answer, since it certainly is possible to display and delete hidden files from the command line.

Comment: The commands you've provided won't work as expected.  The rmdir /s command deletes the hidden files.